# Simple input field using GuidedStepFragment

Tags: android-tv

In `onCreateActions` I'm trying to get a simple input field, where user can input his data. The closest I came was

```
actions.add(GuidedAction.Builder(this.activity)
                .description("")
                .descriptionEditInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
                .descriptionEditable(true)
                .build())
```

Put this requires:
User to click "enter" first (to open "edit" mode of field). I would like to have it opened already (like a simple input field - similar to editText on mobile).

Comment: don't think that it's possible and this editable has other issues: can not paste to it. Don't handle TAB navigation on keyboard properly.